# PHP status text doesn't work

Tags: php, header, status, http-response-codes

I've got a strange case.

On my VirtualMachine, with Ubuntu Server, I've this code that works fine:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 200 USER-007");
```

In my JavaScript I get rightly

```
status: 200
statusText: USER-007
```

But if I upload the entire website on the server online, I get always

```
status: 200
statusText: OK
```

Comment: what do you mean by *upload the entire website*?